# Циклический сдвиг числа влево,битово

Tags: c, циклы, битовые-операции

Необходимо сделать циклический сдвиг влево двоичного кода на 1 позицию, то есть число 130:10000010 будут переведены в 5: 00000101, я код написал но не понимаю почему он не работает, если не сложно прошу объяснить почему мой код не работает и что я могу исправить, сделать на C без дополнительных библиотек кроме iostream.

```
int n, nMask; //Создаётся первым число,2 маска числа
cin >> n; 
nMask = n; //Копирую в маску
int pos = 31; //Нахожу позицию элемента с право который нужно переключить на 1
bool show = false; //Помогает не искать после нахождения старшего бита
for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (n >> i & 1 && show) {
        show = true; //Этот if станет неактивным после того как show станет true
        pos -= i; //Убираю от позиций шаги которые пришлось проделать и получаю бит который нужно переключить
    }
}
nMask ^= 1 << pos; //Изменяю определённый элемент бита на 1 
n = n | ~nMask; //Копирую изменённую маску с переключёнными битами если он встретит 0 и 1 то он включит его на 1
cout << (int)n; //Вывод нового числа
```

Comment: Какого именно размера числа? int - это 4 байта, вы приводите пример с 8 битами...

Comment: Я использовал двоичный код,по поводу int я не понял вопроса.

Comment: Если 130 - байт, будет 5. Если 130 - int, то вы получите 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000100. Так понятнее?

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/bitops.h#L75

Comment: Не стал подробно разбираться в Вашем коде, тем более ,что ответ уже есть. Но вот эта строчка - **how = true; //Этот if станет неактивным после того как show станет true**.... Вообще-то, с точностью до наоборот. У Вас условие никогда не выполнится, т..к **bool show = false;** и  **if (n >> i & 1 *&& show*)**

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код сложен, непонятно, что вы пытаетесь делать. Так, как мне кажется, проще:

```
unsigned int rol(unsigned int x, unsigned int n)
{
    n %= 32;
    return (x << n) | (x >> (32-n));
}

unsigned char rol(unsigned char x, unsigned int n)
{
    n %= 8;
    return (x << n) | (x >> (8-n));
}
```

Пожалуй, можно даже так:

```
template<typename T,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
T rol(T x, unsigned int n)
{
    using unsigT = typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type;
    unsigT y = x;
    n %= sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT;
    return (y << n) | (y >> (sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT-n));
}
```

Comment: А что за код вы скинули в первый раз,и как он работает ? в int x я ввожу шаги,в n ввожу своё число но почему я потом иду в обратном направлений ?

Comment: Показываю на байте. Например, 01100011, сдвиг на 2. Первая часть - сдвиг влево на 2, получаем 10001100, вторая - вправо на 6, получаем 00000001 (старшие два бита стали младшими). Делаем "или" - все, нужное количество битов перенеслось из старших в младшие - 10001101...

Comment: Я ввёл 130 и итерацию в 1 после чего вывелось число 4,хотя должно было вывести 5,я вашу идею понял но не понял реализацию :D

Comment: https://ideone.com/DlGlvF

Comment: Я бы добавил `n%=32` в первом случае - ну, потому что циклическое смещение на 32 бита это то же самое, что никакого.

Comment: @Mikhailo Спасибо, исправляюсь :)

Comment: @Mikhailo, а я бы этого не делал, так как это прячет очевидные UB. Если компилятор довольно педантичный, то может и сказать пользователю.

Comment: @0andriy А в чем тут UB?..

Comment: @Mikhailo, начнём с того, что `unsigned int` -- это 32-битное число. Продолжим тем, что сдвиг больше, чем на соответствующее количество бит -- это UB. В стандарте описано

Comment: @0andriy В предложенном мною варианте брать остаток от деления никак не может быть сдвига больше чем на 32 разряда. А циклический сдвиг вообще в стандарте отсутствует.

Comment: @Mikhailo так я об этом и говорю, что таким образом скрывается потенциальное UB, если ошибка где-то в другом месте.